# Theming paragraph fields from entity reference in view

Tags: views, 8, entities

I have a `view` (Drupal 8) where I load my `entity reference` field (display hidden), with three fields from a `Paragraph type` and a certain custom display).

The HTML markup looks like this now:

```
<div class="paragraph paragraph--type--par-organization-employee paragraph--view-mode--relationship-details-org-view">
  <div class="field field--name-field-par-organization-reference field--type-entity-reference field--label-hidden field__item">
    <a href="/node/9" hreflang="nl">Sogeti</a></div>
  <div class="field field--name-field-par-phone-number field--type-telephone field--label-hidden field__items">
    <div class="field__item">020-55883366</div>
  </div>
  <div class="field field--name-field-par-email field--type-email field--label-hidden field__item">
    <a href="mailto:test@sogeti.nl">test@sogeti.nl</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't find a way how to theme the fields. I don't get any template suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where i had to theme entity reference fields that were used in a view. Have you tried any of these?

1. Setup a view mode for the Paragraph type, set view Format to Show Content where the view mode was set to the one you needed, and then i themed the view mode
2. Use a [hook_preprocess_hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x) to get all the results from a View and then store them in the $variables['fields'] and then you modify the twig template for the view

This relies on [Views Template Files](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.2.x) and [Debugging Twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates)